# I am using google analytics in my project does that requires AdSupport Framework

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am using google analytics in my project and that requires Adsupport framework.
When i am using AdSupport framework my app gets rejected showing the message:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "Zee News English". To process your delivery, the following issues
>   must be corrected:
>
> Improper Advertising Identifier [IDFA] Usage. Your app contains the
>   Advertising Identifier [IDFA] API but you have not indicated its usage
>   on the Prepare for Upload page in iTunes Connect.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page
>   and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission
>   process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then
>   deliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,

Should I Select the option of IDFA when publishing the app on iTunes.Besides google analytics i am not using any advertising thing.

Comment: I am currently experiencing the same issue... For previous updates (latest was two weeks ago), this error does not appear.
Please update this topic if you find a solution !

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: Since I'm in the same situation as pooja_1205, I answer to your question @Eduardo : I'm using Xcode freshly updated (5.1.1) on a MacBook Pro (10.9.2) and iOS SDK 7.1.

Comment: What I mean is what version of the Google Analytics iOS SDK. Seems like there was a related change on version 3.03a and 3.03c last February. You should make sure you are using the latest version. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/changelog

Comment: I am using google analytics ios_3.06

Comment: possible duplicate of [App rejected because of "improper IDFA" while I'm not using any advertising service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498352/app-rejected-because-of-improper-idfa-while-im-not-using-any-advertising-serv)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an **up to date Google Analytics SDK** ([you can check here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/resources)), make sure that :

- You don't have a **reference to AdSupport framework** anymore ([not needed since 3.0.3c GA SDK version, for GA basic uses](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/changelog)) ;
- You don't have a **reference to libAdIdAccess.a**, because it requires the AdSupport framework ;
- You have a reference to **libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a**.

Possible useful link : https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=387

Comment: this worked!!!But i have already submitted my app with IDFA selected due to the presence of adsupport framework but my app is not showing any ads.will there be any problem due to this thing.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/ link you provided says that libAdIdAccess.a and AdSupport framework are required!

Comment: @hasan83 Yep, it says that `libAdIdAccess.a` and `AdSupport.framework` are required **"to use the IDFA (Identifier for Advertisers)"**. If you just use GA without any advertising in your app, so you don't need to link theses two references anymore. Because **"Google Tag Manager no longer has a dependency on AdSupport.framework by default"** [(changelog for Release Version 3.03c February 19, 2014)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/changelog).

Comment: I am serving ads in my app. using Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK. I managed to integrate it and it doesn't need AdSupport.framework. I ended with removing it. but still have libAdIdAccess.a. I don't remember now how tracking is working. maybe I downgraded the tracking library, I am not sure. thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Remember that IDFA is not only used for showing advertising in your app, if you want to have demographic information in GA you will get it with the IDFA. So if you want to track this info you need IDFA as well.