# App rejected because of "improper IDFA" while I'm not using any advertising service

Tags: ios, google-analytics, app-store, app-store-connect

I use **Google Analytics** in my app, so it needs the **AdSupport framework**. Since yesterday, my app is rejected when I try to publish an update, with the following error message :

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "Zee News English". To process your delivery, the following issues
>   must be corrected:
>
> Improper Advertising Identifier [IDFA] Usage. Your app contains the
>   Advertising Identifier [IDFA] API but you have not indicated its usage
>   on the Prepare for Upload page in iTunes Connect.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page
>   and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission
>   process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then
>   deliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,

When I publish the update, I can't check the *"Does this app use the Advertising Identifier ?"* box, because I **DO NOT use any advertising** in my app ! So what can I do ?

The last updates were fine, I've just add minor bug fixes in this update.

Comment: Did you go through these search results? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+idfa+google

Comment: Yes, but nothing helped me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google has released Google Analytics Services iOS SDK v3.03c, which provides an option to remove the AdSupport.framework dependency.

Apps that need to access the advertising identifier (IDFA) string and advertiser tracking enabled flag as part of their Google Tag Manager implementation should link to libAdIdAccess.a, now included in the GA Services SDK download.

See the full changelog entry here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/changelog

Download the latest SDK here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/resources

Comment: It was that ! The last Google Analytics SDK versions don't need the AdSupport framework anymore, if you basically use the GA SDK (my case). Thank you Rakesh.

Comment: So if I don't want to use IDFA, what should I do? Remove the AdSupport.framework dependency? Is there anything to be done in the code? I have not enabled IDFA anywhere in the project.